# Whitespace characters messes up a shell script grep pattern for extracting markdown links (macOS)

Tags: macos, shell, grep, markdown

I am working on a tool to convert markdown files to text bundles, [revising a great piece of code from Zett](https://gist.github.com/Zettt/c8797b89390c6c84cc19d337e51e45c7) to use on macOS since I will be porting my Apple Notes files to Craft.

I have problems parsing all links into an array using grep. No matter how hard I try using options like `--null` and `| xargs -0`, the result ends up being split by whitespace characters:

```
targets=($(grep '!\[.*\](.*)' "$inFile"))
```

An example: I have a small markdown test file containing the following:

```
# Allan Falk - ComicWiki

**Allan Falk - ComicWiki**

![Allan Falk - ComicWiki](images/Allan%20Falk%20-%20ComicWiki.png)

http://comicwiki.dk/wiki/Allan_Falk
```

Running the above code creates the following array in where the markdown link is split up like so:

```
![Allan
Falk
-
ComicWiki](images/Allan%20Falk%20-%20ComicWiki.png)
```

How can I get complete links as individual array entries (they will be processed later individually, using `sed` for copying files etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `IFS=` (null value) and use read like this:

```sh
IFS= read -ra arr < <(grep '!\[.*\]' file)

# examine array
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="![Allan Falk - ComicWiki](images/Allan%20Falk%20-%20ComicWiki.png)")'
```

`<(grep '!\[.*\]' file)` runs `grep` using *process substitution* and `<` before that sends output of this command to `read`

[Working Demo](https://ideone.com/G6fNiS)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I am getting a `syntax error near unexpected token '('` message (by the IFS code). I must admit I am not familiar with using IFS, but I tried to use the code as you wrote it.

Comment: That error means you are using some other shell. Make sure you are running in `bash`.

Comment: I thought that `#!/bin/sh` also somehow embraced `bash` in macOS? I prefer to keep it in `sh` for compatibility's sake and avoid running into more errors in the rest of the script… Thank you again for your kind help.

Comment: MacOS comes with `bash` 3.2.x and there is no reason to not to use it.

Comment: Substituting `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/bash` gives me an error as well. I accidentally omitted one of the less-than signs, yet I get a `syntax error near unexpected token '<'` message. Same error as well as with the previous code. Looks like this to accommodate the variables in the script: `IFS= read -ra targets < <(grep '!\[.*\]' $inFile)`...

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your full shell script

Comment: I have included a working demo of this code in my answer

Comment: I appreciate your help! Yet, I figured out that it was only a question about adding an extra set of quotation marks, that solved my initial problem. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging, I found out that I was missing quotations in my statement. So instead of writing:

```
targets=($(grep '!\[.*\](.*)' "$inFile"))
```

I needed to add quotation marks inside the first set of brackets:

```
targets=( "$(grep '!\[.*\](.*)' "$inFile")" )
```

Now the array works fine – no whitespace splitting occurs.

Comment: `(.*)` has no use in grep. Just `'!\[.*\]'` is enough